# Enterprise Architect open two properties windows simultaneously

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to open two properties windows at the same time? For example, say I want to double click on MyClass1(or right click and select Properties), and also double click on MyClass2 so that I can compare. Is this possible?

As a related question: Is there a way to open both the Attributes And the Operations window for a class diagram at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and no.

The dialogs are modal and only one can be open at a time.

The element browser (under the Element menu) provides you with a tree view of information related to an element, which can be a more convenient way to open the attribute and operation dialogs, but you can still only work in one at a time.